# Connect to existing MySQL database on server from local computer

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to connect to an existing mysql database on a linux server and scaffold tables in my project and working with them via EFCore.

I use this command line to scaffold :

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server={IP};port={PORT};userid={USER_ID};password={PASSWORD};database={DB_NAME};" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -o Models -f
```

But it shows this error to me:

```
Host '{MY_IP}' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I am using `Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql` library on `.NET Core 2.1 SDK`

What should I do?

Comment: Connecting from external machines should be allowed and configured on mysql itself.

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL instance is bound to the public IP address (you can check this by doing 3306 port scan for that IP - assuming MySQL is running on the standard port) then you need to grant privileges on the database for the user you are using as follows:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <yourdb>.* TO `<youruser>`@`<yourip>` IDENTIFIED by '<yourpassword>';
```

After you have run this you need to run the `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` command.  Assuming all above conditions are met you should be able to access your DB remotely.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 things to understand before trying to connect.

1) Generally, databases are allowed to listen to local machine, ie localhost.

2) databases as mysql authentication comes in pair i.e. user@host_name.

So changing the way DB want you are really screwing security.

**Now here is the way you can change MySQL listen for rest of world.**

```
1) go to **my.cnf**, Check ‘**bind-address**’, comment this line. it
must be bind with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.  

2) go to database MySQL, table users, column host replace
`localhost` to `"%"`, so the anyone from anywhere can connect.  

3) `CREATE USER ‘root’@‘%’ IDENTIFIED BY ‘some_pass’`;  

4) `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO ‘root’@‘%’;`  

5) `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
```